# Mysql Duplicate count

Tags: php, mysql

Good day. i would like to store the total of all IDnumber. but if it has a duplicate it is count as one.

`IDNumber`

ID1

ID1

ID2

ID2

ID3

This is the output iwant Total is '3'

my current output is

count(*)

2

2

1

Here is my sample query

```
SELECT count(*) FROM esd_user GROUP BY IDNumber
```

Comment: What's the issue, aren't you getting the desired result if not then how about pasting your table and data too.

Comment: I want to show the result of total. but my output is

Count(*)
2
2
1

Iwant the total result which is '3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
select count(*) from(
    select distinct IDNumber from esd_user 
) as a
```

Comment: i received an error Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias 0.000 sec

Comment: IT sums all the value and it returns with all of the data. total of '5'